# Play games snapshots vs firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-play-games

I am creating simple android game and I want to save user progress on backend, nothing too complicated, only lets say json with map of completed/uncompleted levels.

I am looking into **play games snapshots** and **firebase database** and I am not sure what to use. Having to solve conflicts manually in play games snapshots seems like unnecessary work, on the other hand I am not sure how play games auth goes with firebase.

Give me some suggestions please

Comment: You can check this blog if you want to save data for the user using Firebase - [Firebase Android Playground — Realtime Database](https://proandroiddev.com/firebase-android-playground-realtime-database-560d4e18404a).

Comment: I spent a bit more time on research and found this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/play-games
You can first sign in the user with play games and then into firebase, so I'll do that